# PHPStorm plugin to collapse JSON

Tags: phpstorm, json

I'm using [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) and I have several JSON files that are fully formatted with indents and new lines.

Is there a plugin I can get for PhpStorm that will allow me to collapse/minify all the JSON in these files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thought: Cannot PHP do that itself? Just citing from my memory:

```
$json_file = '/path/to/file.json';  /* dynamically set the name of your JSON file here */
file_put_contents($json_file,       /* Write back to disk */
  json_encode(                      /* Re-Encode to JSON */
    json_decode(                    /* Decode original JSON object */
      file_get_contents($json_file) /* Read the original JSON file from disk */
    )
  )
);
```

No safeguard in yet, but of course you can split that up to only write the file if no errors have occured. Reading above code bottom-up, you

1. read the original file (including indents etc) from disk
2. decode it to make it a PHP object (indents etc. lost here)
3. encode it back to JSON (no intents, as they were lost in previous step – this will result in a one-line string)
4. write the newly created (one-liner) JSON back to disk.

Put the entire thing in a loop to process all your JSON files:

```
foreach ( glob('/path/to/dir/*.json') as $json_file ) {
  file_put_contents($json_file,json_encode(json_decode(file_get_contents($json_file))));
}
```

Do we really need a plugin for what can be done by a one-liner? ;)

**EDIT:** As [ComFreek](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/583/comfreek) pointed out in his comment, `json_decode()` only deals with UTF-8. So if your files use a different charset, you might want to add a call to `utf8_encode()` to wrap around `file_get_contents()`, so the "innermost command" of above loop reads `utf8_encode(file_get_contents($json_file))`. for completeness:

```
foreach ( glob('/path/to/dir/*.json') as $json_file ) {
  file_put_contents($json_file,json_encode(json_decode(utf8_encode(file_get_contents($json_file)))));
}
```

Comment: I would be careful in regards to charsets and encodings. `json_decode()` only deals with UTF-8 ([source](http://de2.php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php#86997)). If the files are already encoded in ASCII or UTF-8, the code will perfectly work.

Comment: @ComFreek thanks for pointing this out! I wasn't aware of this, as I usually deal with UTF8 only when it comes to JSON. Updated my answer accordingly, giving you credit of course :)

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again, but [`utf8_encode()`](http://php.net/utf8_encode) doesn't do what you probably think it does (blame PHP). It requires the input string to be in [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). One must use [`iconv()`](http://php.net/iconv) to convert between character encodings.

Comment: Yeah, all those nasty details :) Well, we're on SoftwareRecs here. I didn't even recommend software, which was quite a little borderline. But we shouldn't dig to deep into programming here. Thanks again for pointing out a culprit, @ComFreek – but I guess if the OP wants to go this path and needs more details, that's rather a case for [SO] then :)

Comment: thanks, although this is not quite the solution i was looking for it should be very easy to implement. Sorry for not getting back sooner, some how real life managed to get in the way :(

Comment: Glad I was able to help! In case you really need to deal with other charsets, please take a look at `iconv` (as suggested by ComFreek) and `recode` (always good to have an alternative available ;) And someone should debug that `realLife()` procedure to figure out why it always comes in between #D